# How to get and generate repetitive numbers (subset) arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I check the code and realized that it can't show repetitive numbers

**MY CODE**

```
      <?php

      /* Designated level for each exp
      Level 2 - 23 exp
      Level 3 - 34 exp
      Level 4 - 45 exp
      Level 5 - 56 exp
      Level 6 - 68 exp
      Level 7 - 79 exp
      Level 8 - 90 exp
      Level 9 - 101 exp
      Level 10 - 112 exp
      Level 11 - 123 exp
      Level 12 - 134 exp
      Level 13 - 145 exp
      Level 14 - 156 exp
      Level 15 - 168 exp
      Level 16 - 179 exp
      */

      $limit =  100000-99370;

      // Level
      $arrlevel = array ('Level 2','Level 3','Level 4','Level 5','Level 6','Level 7','Level 8','Level 9','Level 10','Level 11','Level 12','Level 13','Level 14','Level 15','Level 16');

      // Exp
      $array = array (23,34,45,56,68,79,90,101,112,123,134,145,156,168,179);

      $array = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($limit) {
      return ($var <= $limit);
      });

      $num = count($array);
      $total = pow(2, $num);
      $out = array();

      for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {

      $comb = array();
      for ($j = 0; $j < $num; $j++) {
      // is bit $j set in $i?
      if (pow(2, $j) & $i){
      $comb[] = $array[$j];
      }
      }

      if (array_sum($comb) == $limit)
      {
      $out[] = $comb;
      }
      }

      array_multisort(array_map('count', $out), SORT_ASC, $out);

      $out = array_unique($out, SORT_REGULAR);
      $m = 1;
      $mapper = [
      23 => "Level 2",
      34 => "Level 3",
      45 => "Level 4",
      56 => "Level 5",
      68 => "Level 6",
      79 => "Level 7",
      90 => "Level 8",
      101 => "Level 9",
      112 => "Level 10",
      123 => "Level 11",
      134 => "Level 12",
      145 => "Level 13",
      156 => "Level 14",
      168 => "Level 15",
      179 => "Level 16",
      ];

      foreach($out as $result)
      echo "<b>Possible Answer ". $m++. " : </b><br> " .implode(' , ', array_map(function($x) use ($mapper) {
      return $mapper[$x] . " - " . $x;
      }, $result))." 
      <br><br>";
```

**My Input and Ouput** 
If i input 99318
the output is like this
Possible Answer 1 :  
Level 10 - 112  ,  Level 11 - 123  ,  Level 12 - 134  ,  Level 13 - 145  ,  Level 15 - 168 

I want to generate also the repetitive numbers too
But it cannot show some repetitive numbers answer like this 
Possible Answer  : 
Level 4 - 45  , Level 10 - 112  ,  Level 11 - 123  , Level 11 - 123  ,  Level 12 - 134  ,  Level 13 - 145 

You can see there's two Level 11 - 123

**I want the ouput like this**
Possible Answer  : 
Level 4 - 45  , Level 10 - 112  ,  Level 11 (x2) - 246  ,  Level 12 - 134  ,  Level 13 - 145 
I want to group all repititive numbers and sum up them all

Comment: Provided code is not generating repetitive numbers with input 99318. Please check you code and fix the question.

Comment: my code is not even generating any repetitive numbers. I do know how to do it. That's i ask that question too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to get your result is to pass another value to array_map with the result of [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Then inside the mapping you can determine to show the count for the number based on the index like `$countValues[$x]` just as for the mapper.

For example

```
foreach($out as $result) {
    $countValues = array_count_values($result);
    echo "<b>Possible Answer " . $m++ . " : </b><br> " . implode(' , ',
            array_map(function ($x) use ($mapper, $countValues) {
                $strCount = $countValues[$x] > 1 ? " (" . $countValues[$x] . ")" : "";
                return $mapper[$x] . $strCount . " - " . $x;
            }, array_unique($result))) . "
      <br><br>";
}
```

That will give you a result like

```
Possible Answer 1 :
Level 2 - 23 , Level 6 - 68 , Level 7 (x2) - 79 , Level 9 - 101 , Level 10 - 112 , Level 15 - 168
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/SUeKl) with as a test a duplicate value 79 for `$array`

Comment: if my limit is this $limit =  100000-99730. the result of this operation is 270. and the result of the program are:  Possible Answer 2 :  Level 2 - 23 , Level 7 - 79 , Level 15 - 168
  Possible Answer 3 : Level 6 - 68 , Level 7 - 79 , Level 11 - 123
 Possible Answer 4 :  Level 7 (x2) - 79 , Level 10 - 112.

Comment: But i want to see some possible results like this : Possible Answer : Level 8 (x3) - 270     AND  Possible Answer : Level 8 (x2) - 180, Level 4 (x2) - 90  which total is 270 too. And How to get the multiply the count to result because in your code output it only shows Level 7 (x2) - 79 and must be Level 7 (x2) - 158

Comment: and the ouput and possible reults are like this : 
Possible Answer 1 : Level 2 - 23 , Level 6 - 68 , Level 16 - 179
Possible Answer 2 : Level 2 - 23 , Level 7 - 79 , Level 15 - 168
Possible Answer 3 : Level 7 (x2) - 158 , Level 10 - 112
Possible Answer 4: Level 8 (x3) - 270 
Possible Answer 5: Level 8 (x2) - 180, Level 4 (x2) - 90

so on...

Comment: It same like this - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combinational-sum/ . but was made in C++ –

Comment: It is not obvious to get that logic from the question. Can your required result be derived from only the `$result` array? What I mean is, is your desired output only based on how to represent the data in `$result`?

Comment: yes, but im not sure if my code can generate repetitive numbers like what i said in my comments

Comment: can you give me an idea to show the results with repetitive ( Possible Answer 5: Level 8 (x2) - 180, Level 4 (x2) - 90 ) and unique numbers ( Possible Answer 1 : Level 2 - 23 , Level 6 - 68 , Level 16 - 179)

Comment: It is still a bit vague to me. If you can provide an array with duplicate values and for that array the desired result, I can take a look if I can help you in the right direction.

Comment: i already confuse to code it.on how  to generate the duplicate / repetitive numbers in result. :(